# NSDictionary losing its contents (exc bad access)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

So i have a uiviewcontroller. It has a property of an NSMutableArray with a nonatomic, retain property synthesized.

In the viewDidLoad I init it with the following, and also add a button to the nav bar.

```
test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [[SearchField alloc] initWithName:@"Subject" :Text], kSubjectKey, 
        [[SearchField alloc] initWithName:@"Source publication" :Text], kSourceKey,
        [[SearchField alloc] initWithName:@"Keyword" :Text], kKeywordKey,
        [[SearchField alloc] initWithName:@"Author" :Text], kAuthorKey,
        [[SearchField alloc] initWithName:@"Color" :Bool], kColorKey,
        nil ];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"lol %d", [test count]]);
```

The first log, when running through the debugger runs fine. However, I have tied the following code to the button:

```
-(void)search:(id)sender{

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"lol %d", [test count]]);
```

When this code executes the log line crashes with exc bad access. *Nothing* is happening to the NSDictionary between the viewDidLoad and the button press, so why is this happening? And more importantly, how do I fix it? :)

Cheers

**Edit**
I thought maybe it was my SearchField class was doing things, so i replaced them with simple strings, the problem still occurs.

Comment: NSLog(@"lol %d", [test count]); i'm not sure this'll solve your error but you dont need to create string object here

Comment: Thanks! I have been creating string objects all the time, pointlessly :)

Comment: Also thanks for all the answers, I fixed it with no problems and I got a better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're directly accessing the member variable - you need to go through the accessor - ie:

```
self.test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObje ...
```

This will make sure your object retains the dictionary.

Comment: For clarity, I'll just add that this advice does not apply under ARC. If you're using ARC and the ivar is synthesised, the compiler will do the retain for you even if you don't use `self.`. (Based on multiple SO answers I've found today.)

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure `test` is a class variable, by setting it up as a property of your view controller's header:

   `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *test;`
2. Release it in your view controller's `-dealloc` method:

   `[test release], test = nil;`
3. Set its value as follows:

   `self.test = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:...];`
4. Access its `count` property as follows:

   `NSLog(@"Count: %u", test.count);`

   Or:

   `NSLog(@"Count: %u", [test count]);`

   Note that `-count` returns an unsigned integer, so you should use `%u` to format its value.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary you're creating is autoreleased. You're using a convenience method (`dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`) which returns a new autoreleased object.

The autoreleased object is being released (and deallocated) some time after its creation, which is why it's crashing later in the program.

You need to retain the returned dictionary, or create a new dictionary using the alloc/init method.

Either way, you need to remember to release the dictionary when you're done with it.

You should read up on the basic memory management rules and conventions for Objective-C.